# How to disable body'scroll while enable div's scroll?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu"></div>
      <div class="list"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
.menu{
float:left;
width:50%;
}
.list{
float:right;
width:50%;
}
```

how to disable the whole html's scroll. but the menu div and list div can scroll vertically?
and dependently?

I mean when I scroll the left div the right div do not have to scroll together.

Comment: Cannot be done only with css, use javascript to add class `.no-scroll{overflow: hidden}` to body.

Comment: @SameerKhan I mean two divs scroll separately, it can not be done?

Comment: Can you please add some more code or create a example what issue you are facing ?

Comment: please check.@SameerKhan

Comment: It doesn't scroll see this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/sameerthekhans/v7zredhu/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to start from the `html` tag down. It and all parents of your scrollable elements should have the height of the viewport.

This means that the `html`, `body`, `.container` and both scrollable elements should have a `height: 100%` or `height: 100vh`.

Then you can make the scrollable elements actually scroll independently by adding `overflow: hidden`.

If this doesn't make sense, please see this [pen](https://codepen.io/scriptex/pen/oNXBamQ) which I made for you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent vertical scrolling on your `.container`. This can be done by using the `overflow` CSS property. Look at the code below on how you can achieve this and also enable vertical scrolling for your two elements (`.list` and `.menu`).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.container {
  max-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.menu {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width:50%;
}
.list {
  overflow-y: auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I have also edited the code a bit. Check it out. It works. To try out, insert a tall element into one of your `div`s (`<h1 style="padding-top: 100vh;">Test</h1>`) inside the `.menu` container and watch as a scroll bar appears just for that `div`.